# Adding code to .txt file without overwriting it

Tags: php

```
<?php

$fn = "content.txt";



if (isset($_POST['content'])){

    $content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);

    $fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");

    $old_content = file_get_contents($fn);

    fputs($fp, $content."\n".$old_content);


    fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");

}

?>



<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">

    <textarea rows="25" cols="40" name="content"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>
```

So this is my php code. But it deletes the the previously written data. How do I make it so that the new piece of data is added on a new line? Keeping the last of the data. 
Thank you!

```
<?php

$fn = "content.txt";



if (isset($_POST['content'])){

    $content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);

    $fp = fopen($fn,"a+") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");

    fputs($fp,$content);


    fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");

}

?>



<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">

    <textarea rows="25" cols="40" name="content"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>
```

Now it doesn't work at all

Comment: Open the file for append - mode `a` or `a+`

Comment: Use `a` or `a+` or `FILE_APPEND` => http://php.net/file_put_contents

Comment: @reidjako Take a look at the PHP documentation for `fopen` - you'll find it enlightening.

Comment: Or [`fopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) I.e.: => `$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'a+');`

Comment: Actually it looks like the OP's trying to _prepend_ to the file, so merely opening in append mode won't cut it... @reidjako, prepending to files is expensive stuff.  If you can't make do do with appedning to the file, you might consider saving into _different_ files and appending them together in reverse chronological order at runtime.

Comment: Did you happen to have tried [`what I posted below?`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22495507/)? @reidjako There are two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Now it doesn't work at all"*

^--« As per your edit, this will write each entry on a new line:

I changed:

```
$content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);
```

to

```
$content = stripslashes($_POST['content'] . "\n");
```

Using `\n` will have all new entries on a new line.

PHP

```
<?php

$fn = "content.txt";

if (isset($_POST['content'])){

    $content = stripslashes($_POST['content'] . "\n");

    $fp = fopen($fn,"a+") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");

    fputs($fp,$content);


    fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");

}

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">

    <textarea rows="25" cols="40" name="content"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>
```

---

Written to file:

a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
Hello world!!
Testing 123

Written to file one at a time:
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5

Entered in the textarea box as shown and written to file as shown:

Hello world!!
Testing 123

---

If you want the data to be entered starting from the top, use:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['content'])){

    $content = stripslashes($_POST['content'] . "\n");

    $file_data = $content;
    $file_data .= file_get_contents('content.txt');
    file_put_contents('content.txt', $file_data);

}

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">

    <textarea rows="25" cols="40" name="content"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

from [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) manual:

> 'a'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the
>   file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

change

```
 $fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
```

to

```
 $fp = fopen($fn,"a") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
```

Comment: this is _append_ing, but the OP is _prepend_ing.

Comment: @DanFarrell OP ask "How do I make it so that the new piece of data is added on a new line?"  i understand that he want to append at the end

Comment: That's not what the original code is doing though.  A line at the beginning of the files is "a new line" too...

Comment: of course the original code add in the begining, that is why he ask how to add at the end...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `a` or `a+` mode instead of `w`, so you can do:

```
$fp = fopen($fn,"a") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
```

instead of:

```
$fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
```

From the **[manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)** about fopen `mode`:

> 'w': Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of
> the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not
> exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'a': Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the
> file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'a+': Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end
> of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your call to `fopen` to use append mode instead of write:

```
$fp = fopen($fn,"a") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 1):

observation - since you were using file_get_contents already I want to mention that there is a reverse function for writing:

`file_put_contents($fn, $content, FILE_APPEND);`

this way you don't even need to open up the text file and load it into memory.

Helpful for logging too.

Comment: good point - but if the OP truly wants to _prepend_ to the existing file content, it will have to be read into memory, or into a temporary "swap" file, anyways.